# search table by search filter in select angular

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-filters

I need setting search filter which show me row with colors when I choose color from select tag? But the filter must working only on columns with number 1-6.

For example when I select "C" then show my only row number 2.

Simple version of my problem in plunker is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/8WkOoKYWetR3uR8qvNO6?p=preview)

I have something like this (code below) but it's not working.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr><th width="7%">Lp.</th>
            <th width="7%">Img</th>
            <th width="10%">Name</th>
            <th width="10%">Colors</th>
            <th ng-repeat="m in [] | rangeFilter:0:pyNumber" ng-class="[{'border': $index+1 == divOne }, {'border': $index+1 == divTwo }, {'border': $index+1 == divThree }]">{{$index+1}}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="articleItem in articleColors">
            <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
            <td>+</td>
            <td>{{ articleItem.nazwa_art }}</td>
            <td>{{ articleItem.kolory_pod }}{{ articleItem.pantony }}</td>
            <td ng-repeat="m in [] | rangeFilter:0:pyNumber" ng-class="[{'border': $index+1 == divOne }, {'border': $index+1 == divTwo }, {'border': $index+1 == divThree }]" >  
                <select id="articleColorsData" name="py{{$index+1}}" class="form-control" ng-model="articleColorsData.kolory[$index]" ng-init="articleColorsData.kolory[$index] = 'x'">
                    <option ng-repeat="oneColor in articleItem.all_colors" ng-value="x"  value="{{ oneColor }}" ng-model="search">{{ oneColor }}</option>
                </select>  
            </td>                                          
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Lp.</th>
            <th>Img</th>
            <th>Name <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i> </th>
            <th>Colors</th>
            <th ng-repeat="y in [] | rangeFilter:0:pyNumber " ng-class="[{'border': $index+1 == divOne }, {'border': $index+1 == divTwo }, {'border': $index+1 == divThree }]">
                {{$index+1}}
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="article in articlesOfDrawings | filter : articleColorsData.kolory[$index]  track by $index" >
            <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
            <td>img</td>
            <td ng-repeat="column in article" id="{{ column[0] }}" style="background-color: rgb({{column[1]}});" ng-class="[{'border-one': $index-1 == divOne  && divOne != 0  }, {'border-two': $index-1 == divTwo && divTwo != 0 }, {'border-three': $index-1 == divThree && divThree != 0 }]" ><p>{{ column[0] }}</p></td> 
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: {{ filter_expression | filter : expression : comparator}} and you have 'y in [] | rangeFilter:0:pyNumber'

Comment: Can you please add some entries of your JSON data to your question? With-out data it's hard to help.

Comment: I think `rangeFilter` is also missing..could you please fix your plunkr first

Comment: @Chris Hermut this rangeFilter is working ok. In on my page it show numbers 1-6, but In plunker I not attached it because it is not irrelevant. Now the plunkr sholud have all data wich need, I saved all again.